# Filter in custom grid doesn't work normally. Magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, magento2.2.6, custom-grid

When I filter twice, it works fine after the third time display only one product in each row.

grid_record_grid_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Grid record list UI Component
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_Grid
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">item_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">item_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="item_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="qty">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Webkul\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Before filter 
[image]

After filter
[image]

Comment: specify which Magento version you are using in question.

Comment: default magento grid works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace data source section to:

```xml
<dataSource name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">item_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">item_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">item_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

I have added storage config settings:

```
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">item_id</item>
</item>
```

Comment: it helped me, but I added xsi: type = "array"> to <item name = "js_config", then it started working, please update your answer so that I choose as the correct answer

Comment: <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">item_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>

Comment: @RobinioTor I have edited the answer.